# Coding for cellphones

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

I have a old LG MG280 cellphone that I'd like to code some simple things for. It has Java support, but I know that it is not simply making a Java ME application. It has to follow some specific specs otherwise the app will not run. Does anyone know what those specs are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaME platforms are made up of a *profile* and a *configuration*. Most mobile phones use some combination of the [Mobile Information Device Profile](http://java.sun.com/products/midp/) (MIDP) and the [Connected Limited Device Configuration](http://java.sun.com/products/cldc/) (CLDC).

The LG MG280 you are interested in uses MIDP-2.0 and CLDC-1.1, which is pretty standard.

To get started with development you'll probably want to be using the [Sun Java Wireless Toolkit](http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/) (frequently abbreviated to SJWT or WTK). Or, if you are a windows user, you can use the (newer) [JavaME SDK 3.0](http://java.sun.com/javame/downloads/sdk30.jsp). This gives you tools needed to compile/package applications and an emulator which lets you run/debug application on a desktop computer.

There are numerous tutorials available online. Here's a few to get you started:

- http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/02/09/j2me1.html
- http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/wtoolkit/
- http://developers.sun.com/mobility/learn/
- http://www.developer.com/java/j2me/article.php/1561591

Answer (score 2):

Find out which [J2ME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Micro_Edition) profile it has - MIDP etc. Then find an appropriate tutorial, [such as this one](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/wtoolkit/).